# getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I wrote a function to return a string to a directory path.I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I think this function is the cause. Do I need to retain the nsstring or something?

```
-(void) getRemoteFiles:(NSMutableArray *) M
{
    [self createFileToAppDirectory];

    if (!networkqueue) {
        networkqueue:[[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    [[self networkQueue] cancelAllOperations];

    [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];


    int i;

    for (i=0; i<[M count]; i++) {
        NSString *url=[M objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* theFileName = [url lastPathComponent];
        NSString *safestring=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if ([theFileName isEqualToString:@"nothing"]==NO) {

            ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:safestring]];
            //think this is causing the problem
            NSString *savepath=[self getDirectoryPathForFileName:theFileName];
            //[request setDownloadDestinationPath:savepath];
            [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
        }

    }

    [[self networkQueue] go];
    //error thrown after this point


}
-(NSString *)getDirectoryPathForFileName:(NSString *)filename

{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSString *newDir;
    BOOL isDir;


    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"remix_data"];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:newDir isDirectory:&isDir]==NO) {
        NSLog(@"dir should exist but does not... go funt dat");
    }

    NSString *localFilePath = [newDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [filemgr release];
    [docsDir release];
    [newDir release];
    return localFilePath;
}
```

Comment: You're not doing alloc/init on filemgr, docsDir and newDir. So why are your releasing them?

Comment: I'm still learning about memory management and the code came from an example. I guess the example is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're actually over-releasing. In getDirectoryPathForFileName, you're releasing docsDir (for example), although you never retained it. You were pulling it out of the dirPaths array, which won't increase the retain count. By releasing it, you're decreasing the retain count, possibly to zero, which will dealloc the string while the array still thinks it is holding it. The next time the array is doing something with that string, your app will crash. Just remove the release calls for docsDir and newDir and you should be good...

Comment: I will try this. Does my usage of nsstring seem ok to you?

Comment: Yep, it appears perfectly reasonable to me, there's no occasion where you've been using it without need or in a wrong way. You just need to get used to those memory management issues, but that's not NSString related... Fear not, you'll get used to it! One rule of thumb: you only need to release something if you created it using a method that begins with init or if you retained it manually.

Answer (score 1):

As always when someone has an EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem I recommend NSZombie. In your particular case it's pretty easy to see why it's crashing, since you're releasing stuff without having alloc'd or retained it first. You should only release stuff you've alloc'd or retained yourself.

In case you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem in the future, that's not as easy to figure out, here's how to use NSZombie:

To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received the release message.

Comment: and don't forget to disable the zombies afterwards. You don't want to hunt down leaks for half an hour just to figure out that you left NSZombies on. Like I did yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

Yes its better to retain the string and release it after use. Also release of the strings `docsDir` and `newDir` is not advised as you are not allocating them. They are auto-release objects.